# ASP.NET application running in IE8 - tab key does not focus on anything but address bar after postback only

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer

I am using ASP.NET with a master form. When I press the tab key IE8 / IE9 moves the focus directly to the address bar. No matter how many times I press the tab key, the focus never makes its way to any of the controls on my web form.

1. TabIndexes have been set (although the browser should be doing this automatically, but I tried this manually to test and nothing worked)
2. After postback, nothing ever gets focus except for the IE address bar.
3. There is an update panel on this form, but even the controls outside of the panel do not get focus, on top of that at some point it was working! Now it does not :(
4. I am at a wall on how to investigate this issue. I am hoping someone else has had/solved this problem and can lend me some advice.

Any help / suggestions / similar experiences are appreciated!

Comment: View the source of the page and copy that HTML to a new static HTML file.  If you have the same problem when viewing that HTML file, then start removing pieces until the problem goes away.  This problem is too generic without knowing the HTML that is causing the issue.

Comment: i know, but there are 4000 lines of markup on this page. 7000 after being rendered. i was putting this out there with hopes of someone already have experienced this. in the meantime i am going to have to do what you suggested. appreciate the input thanks. @David

Comment: Look for keypress related code in the javascript...

Comment: @MartinMilan thanks, that is good advice. there is some code for that, but its only capturing the backspace key. i will keep searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. A modal popup extender was making this happen. Apparently a popup was showing, but because it was nested inside a hidden div it could not be seen. This gave the illusion that the tab key was not behaving correctly. I hope this could help someone in the future.